# How to mount image.iso and create an option in Grub to install?

Tags: installation, grub2, mount, iso

Every now and then new versions of os are released. I want to try them out but what I don't want to have to burn a new CD/DVD or create a bootable USB, every time.

I don't want to use usb or cd/dvd.

How can we install an iso from grub when the computer starts?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847) it might help you accomplish just what you want.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: That's even better :)

Answer (score 0):

im going to guess you are trying to install without a disc, im my experience the iso mounting occurs when the system loads and its after grub, may i suggest opening or mounting the iso and copying the files onto a USB, that should work, oh and make sure the partition settings of the usb are the same, eg the partition can be booted.

If yyou are trying to instyall ubuntu, may i suggest the [Startup Disk Creator] App, ive never tried it but ive heard of it and can see it

Comment: I tried but I got an error, and I want to find a easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need is a MultiSystem. It uses similar option as GRUB and you can mount almost any ISO file. Worked well for me.

http://liveusb.info/dotclear/